# Using lambda on lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to use lambda on lower_bound in c++. I have defined a struct

```
struct Mop{
    Mop( string n, int a){
        name = n;
        age  = a;
    }
    string name;
    int     age;
    bool operator < ( const Mop&a) const {
        return age < a.age;
    }
};
```

and add function

```
void AddVector(vector<Mop> &a, string n , int aa){
    Mop mop(n,aa);
    auto it = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), aa , [](const Mop &ar, const Mop &br){ return ar < br;});
    a.insert(mop,it);
}
int main()
{
    vector<Mop> a;
    AddVector(a,"John",15);
    AddVector(a,"Swan",10);
    return 0;
}
```

But it keep throwing error regarding lambda :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'lower_bound(std::vector<Mop>::iterator, std::vector<Mop>::iterator, int&, AddVector(std::vector<Mop>&, std::string, int)::__lambda0)'
```

I have been searching and the lambda syntax should be corect , why does it keep throwing the error? I tried adding

```
ar.age and br.age
```

to lambda didn't work either.

Whats wrong this lambda?

Comment: Did you include `algorithm`?

Comment: What compiler?  Once you pass mop to lower_bound, and swap the arguments to insert, it wfm with cpp.sh:  cpp.sh/3ucf4  I also pulled the lambda out into a separate named variable (keeps line length down).

Comment: in `vector::insert`, an iterator goes first

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59a84e37ab0eac22

Answer (score 4):

You created `mop` object to use as a comparison key, but you are passing `aa` instead, which represents the "raw" age:

```
auto it = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), aa , [](const Mop &ar, const Mop &br){ return ar < br;});
//                                        ^^
a.insert(mop,it);
//       ^^^ ^^
// Arguments are swapped
```

should be

```
auto it = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), mop, [](const Mop &ar, const Mop &br){ return ar < br;});
//                                        ^^^
a.insert(it, mop);
//       ^^  ^^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/l3S2vc)

Comment: Note that the lambda is redundant, since it will do the same thing as the default comparator. The call can just be `lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), mop);`

Comment: @Johnyb It was a different, but very similar, error - you swapped args of `insert`, it should be `a.insert(it, mop);` ([demo](http://ideone.com/l3S2vc))

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It is in this example, but I strongly suspect the OP is simplifying his problem before posting to SO.  This is a **good** thing.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda syntax is correct, the problem is the 3rd argument passed to [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), it should be value to compare the element of the `vector<Mop>`, i.e. a `Mop`, not an `int`.

BTW: `a.insert(mop,it);` should be `a.insert(it, mop);`.